# I've got an error for my calculator program C++

Tags: c++, syntax-error, calculator

I was trying to make a calculator for one of my firsts projects in C++ but I was getting an error.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int a;
int b;
int sum;
int opp;
int yn;


int main()
{

    cout << "Enter your first value" << endl;
    cin >> a;

    cout << "Type the number that corrosponds to your opperation \n 1.add \n 2.subtract \n 3.mutipliy \n 4.divide" << endl;
    cin >> opp;

    cout << "Choose your last value" << endl;
    cin >> b;

    return 0;

}

int action()
{

    switch(opp)
    {
    case 1:
        sum = a + b;
        cout << "Your answer is " << sum << endl;
        break;

    case 2:
        sum = a - b;
        cout << "Your answer is " << sum << endl;
        break;

    case 3:
        sum = a * b;
        cout << "Your answer is " << sum << endl;
        break;

    case 4:
        sum = a / b;
        cout << "Your answer is " << sum << endl;
        break;

    case >> 5:
        cout << "Type the number that corrosponds to your opperation \n 1.add \n 2.subtract \n 3.mutipliy \n 4.divide"
    }

    cout << "Would you like to use another oppperation? \n Type the number that relates to the answer you want to choose \n 1.Yes \n 2.No" << endl;
    cin >> yn;

    if (yn = 1)
    {

    cout << "what would you like your nxt opperation to be? \n 1.add \n 2.subtract \n 3.mutiply \n 4.divide" << endl;
        cin >> opp;

        return 0;
    }
}
```

I know it is not the best written code but I am more focused on getting it to work.

If it helps the error code I was getting was:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  calculator.cpp
1>c:\users\"my acount"\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\calculator.cpp(12): error C2365: 'yn' : redefinition; previous definition was 'function'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\math.h(1002) : see declaration of 'yn'
1>c:\users\"my account"\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\calculator.cpp(56): error C2059: syntax error : '>>'
1>c:\users\"my account"\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\calculator.cpp(61): error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'double (__cdecl *)(int,double)' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(485): could be 'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char>> *)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(466): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(void *&)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(448): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(long double &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(430): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(double &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(411): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(float &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(392): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(unsigned __int64 &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(373): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(__int64 &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(353): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(unsigned long &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(335): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(long &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(317): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(unsigned int &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(291): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(int &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(272): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(unsigned short &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(237): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(short &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(218): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(std::_Bool &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(211): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(std::ios_base &(__cdecl *)(std::ios_base &))'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(204): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char>> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_ios<char,std::char_traits<char>> &))'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(198): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::operator >>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &(__cdecl *)(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &))'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(1103): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator >><char,std::char_traits<char>,double(int,double)>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &&,_Ty (__cdecl &))'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=double (int,double)
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(1093): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,unsigned char &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(1086): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,unsigned char *)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(1079): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,signed char &)'
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 12.0\vc\include\istream(1072): or       'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::operator >><std::char_traits<char>>(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,signed char *)'
1>          while trying to match the argument list '(std::istream, double (__cdecl *)(int,double))'
1>c:\users\"my account"\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\consoleapplication1\consoleapplication1\calculator.cpp(63): error C2659: '=' : function as left operand
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

If you can try and explain the answer so I can lern from it, as this is my first project.

Comment: Namespace collision, for one thing. Forever banish `using namespace std;` from your programming vocabulary.

Comment: Default in switch could be useful  to let user know if given unsupported input. You can print out an error message.

Comment: Note that only the result of addition is a *sum* — you have a naming problem.

Answer (score 10):

1. `int yn;`

Here you re-declared `yn` because `math.h` already has a variable named `yn`:

```
extern double yn _PARAMS((int, double));
```

So rename `yn`.

2. `case >> 5:` is wrong, change it to `case 5:`
3. `if (yn = 1)` will always be `true`, as its an assignment operation rather Comparison operator (`==`). Rewrite it as `if (yn == 1)`.

Answer (score 4):

According to the error message, your `<cmath>` defines (or includes something that defines) something called `yn`.

And since you're pulling everything from inside `std::` to the global namespace (with `using namespace std;`), your own `yn` clashes with the `yn` inside `std::`.

Solution: **stop using `using namespace std;`**.

Answer (score 2):

Well lets just read the output of the compiler.

> \calculator.cpp(12): error C2365: 'yn' : redefinition;
>      previous definition was 'function'
>          \include\math.h(1002) : see declaration of 'yn'

that first line tells us that there is already of definition of 'yn'
being used. That second line
tells us where: In the math.h file you included. To fix this, choose
another name for 'yn' in your main.cpp file (or you can remove the "using namespace std" line, and append "std::" to the beginning of every call to cout and so on, but I don't think you will know whats really going on there at this stage)

> \calculator.cpp(56): error C2059: syntax error : '>>'

This is just saying that there is incorrect syntax, and rightfully so. Take those << out of your last "case", and make it look like every other case you did before that, e.g. "case 5:" This would be just a simple typo on your part.

> \calculator.cpp(61): error C2679: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'double (__cdecl *)(int,double)' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

This is something I believe is also a result of the redefinition of "yn" and it is treating "yn" as something you don't want it to be, and it doesn't make sense for the >> operator to be used on it. You would use it on a string for instance, as you probably know.

After that it looks like it lists all the ways you can use it, which for the most part isn't immediately important to you.

> \calculator.cpp(63): error C2659: '=' : function as left operand

Here you are mistaking the assignment operator (=) for the comparison operator (==). The former assigns values as you have been doing, and the latter produces a boolean of "true" or "false" for usage in, say, if statements. You want the latter, so replace the "=" with "==".

Learn to read through the output of the compiler. It actually says useful stuff, you just have to learn to use it.